# ImageMapster not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

recently i've been doing an webpage, which includes using image mapping. By main goal now is to highlight the areas of the image with mouseover so I decided to use ImageMapster, but for some reason it's not working at all.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>jeKnowledge's Interative Website</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IMAGE MAPSTER-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.imagemapster" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div>

        <map name="webjek">
            <area href = "#" shape="poly" coords="0, 474, 12, 464, 31, 462, 46, 465, 64, 477, 74, 499, 81, 518, 72, 533, 71, 544, 73, 552, 91, 551, 103, 556, 116, 560, 131, 580, 144, 603, 152, 624, 162, 644, 158, 652, 162, 650, 174, 667, 245, 667, 246, 615, 253, 603, 264, 592, 275, 589, 286, 550, 318, 526, 349, 508, 344, 500, 343, 492, 347, 483, 351, 478, 357, 448, 375, 428, 403, 430, 421, 437, 431, 455, 429, 480, 424, 498, 421, 515, 443, 514, 469, 533, 481, 559, 497, 591, 493, 592, 508, 614, 520, 644, 540, 641, 530, 665, 538, 667, 0, 666" alt="inovacao" title="Departamento de Inovação"/>
            <area href="#" shape="poly" class="{fillColor:'00ff00'}"coords="1064, 668, 1110, 481, 1348, 550, 1346, 667" alt="sjmeeting" title="Summer Jade Meeting" />
            <area href="#" shape="poly" coords="868, 456, 942, 191, 1128, 212, 1040, 517, 865, 464" alt="rec" title="Recrutamento" />
            <area href="#" shape="poly" coords="458, 105, 458, 155, 491, 154, 491, 166, 518, 168, 519, 118, 490, 119, 489, 105" alt="shifth" title="ShiftHappens" />

        </map>

    </div>


    <div id="background"><img class="mapper" id="myimage" src="C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\projeto jeKnowledge\image.jpg" alt="" usemap="#webjek"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

jQuery:

```
var main = function(){

    $('img').mapster('highlight')
        $('img').mapster('highlight',"key")
        $('img').mapster('highlight',false) 
        $('area').mapster('highlight');




}  

$(document).ready(main);
```

There's also CSS code but i don't think that's relevant. Thanks!

Comment: People who answered really did a good job and I think they understood. They detected several errors which would be impossible to detect if I didn't post all this code, so I don't really see the point of reworking the topic. I even think it might help other people, but if you want to leave it on hold just leave it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't initiate it the right way. Here's how I use it in a project to do a "highlight" in white on mouse hover:

```
    $('#example').mapster({
            singleSelect: true,
            fill : true,
            fillOpacity : 0.6,
            fillColor: 'ffffff',
            onMouseover: function(e) {
                $(this).mapster('set',false).mapster('set',true);
            },
            onMouseout: function(e) { 
                 $(this).mapster('set',false);
            }
        });
```

You have to call all the parameters that way when you initiate it and not one by one.

I think you should consider reading the documentation and checking out the example for an hour maybe before starting to use it. It may seems complicated at first but it is pretty straith forward in the end. You'll see here how to call parameters, what do they do and how to use mapster properly.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html

Comment: That was my first approach, the code looked really similar to yours, only diference was instead of #example i had #myimage but it still wouldn't work :/

Comment: Oh you have a 404 error on this one... no .js extension at the end of your imagemapster jquery

Comment: 2 full days changing code, trying everything and I was missing a .js :|

Comment: Lolllll, always use chrome console to debug you'll usually see your error pretty quick using that

Comment: Thanks for the tip :p It's my first time doing something like this, and I only have 4 days to do it so i try to be as fast as possible :p

Answer (score 3):

In `<head>`

```
<script src="jquery.imagemapster" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Set your file path correctly.

Comment: oh my god, I was missing the .js!! Thank you :D